# When I move project to live server getting this error

Tags: concrete5

When I move project to live server getting this error .This error is on concrete 5..

```
Whoops \ Exception \ ErrorException (E_ERROR)  Class '\Application\Block\ParallaxSection\Controller' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had a block in the overrides directory (/applications/blocks/parralax_section) but it's not there now?

Maybe you converted it to a package, but used the same database where you had installed it via the override directory?

Whatever the case, I'd say find the block folder and throw it in that directory, or worst case scenario just stub out a block folder called parallax_section with a controller that doesn't do anything, and that would make it not explode at the least.